# Project setup Android game with Firebase and Google Play Games for two flavors

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-games, google-developers-console

Sorry if this question may seem trivial, but I'm still very new to `Android`. I read the Google documentations over and over again, but they didn't make it clear for me how to combine these services in a project and I'm afraid I might setup the project wrong.

### Problem

I want to setup a game (com.mycompany.mygame), which will use `Google Game services`  , `In-App Billing` and `Firebase Analytics`. For testing the game, I would like to use `Alpha` and `Beta` releases with tester groups, e.g. to test a new feature, which should not be visible in the release version.

### Question

What would be the correct way to setup this project in the `Google Play Developer`  and `Firebase` consoles? Would this be a correct approach:

#### Application

One application in the All applications view in the `Google Play Developer Console`.

#### Game services

Link two apps in the `Game services` in the `Google Play Developer Console`, both using the same package name com.mycompany.mygame, but with different signing certificates (debug and release). In the `Google Play Developer Console`in the `linked apps` - section it says package name, but I think the application ID is meant? 
Screenshot of package name below).

[image: 1]

Or would it be better to create a two flavors with two different package names, e.g. com.mycompany.mygame and com.mycompany.mygame.dev or will this make problems with authentification with `Google Play Game services`?

#### Firebase

Add two apps, both with the same package name but different signing certificates? Or like written above, two flavors with different package names?

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html

Comment: @Doug Thank you for the link, for our small indie project that would mean two apps with two different package names. Would this make problems with the Play Services? In the documentation it says: You should create two client IDs, one with the release certificate fingerprint and another with the debug certificate fingerprint. Make sure to use the same package name for both. This allows Google Play games services to recognize calls from your linked APKs that are signed with either certificate. - https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling